# counting entries in big data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a tab separated file:

```
A    B    C    D
a    d    ii   do 
a    d    g    do
a    h    g    do
a    i    k    mo
c    i    k    mo
c    g    ii   mo
v    g    p    do
```

I want to count each entry in first column and all related entries to it in second, third, and fourth column like:

```
a 4 d 2 h 1 i 1 ii 1 k 1 domain 3 motif 1
c 2 i 1 g 1 k 1 ii 1 motif 2 
v 1 g 1 p 1 motif 1
```

I am trying to sort  this data with python pandas by these commands:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter= '\t', names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) 
df1.groupby(['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']).count()
```

but it does not return the desired results.

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'v'],
                   'B': ['d', 'd', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'g', 'g'],
                   'C': ['ii', 'g', 'g', 'k', 'k', 'ii', 'p'],
                   'D': ['domain', 'domain', 'domain', 'motif', 
                         'motif', 'motif', 'domain']})

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars='A')
count = melted.groupby(['A', 'value'])['value'].count()
result = count.unstack(fill_value=0)
result['A'] = df.groupby('A')['A'].count()
print(result)
```

yields

```
value  d  domain  g  h  i  ii  k  motif  p  A
A                                            
a      2       3  2  1  1   1  1      1  0  4
c      0       0  1  0  1   1  1      2  0  2
v      0       1  1  0  0   0  0      0  1  1
```

---

**Explanation**:

- Use [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) to coalesce all the columns (except the `A` column) into a single column:

  ```
  In [517]: melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars='A'); melted
  Out[517]: 
      A variable   value
  0   a        B       d
  1   a        B       d
  2   a        B       h
  3   a        B       i
  4   c        B       i
  ...
  ```
- Then you can [groupby/count](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) the `A` and `value` columns:

  ```
  In [520]: count = melted.groupby(['A', 'value'])['value'].count(); count
  Out[520]: 
  A  value 
  a  d         2
     domain    3
     g         2
     h         1
  ...
  ```
- [`count.unstack('value')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) moves the `value` index level into a column index level:

  ```
  In [522]: count.unstack('value', fill_value=0)
  Out[522]: 
  value  d  domain  g  h  i  ii  k  motif  p
  A                                         
  a      2       3  2  1  1   1  1      1  0
  c      0       0  1  0  1   1  1      2  0
  v      0       1  1  0  0   0  0      0  1
  ```

Comment: Very nice! What if you also wanted to include the count of the `A` column (as in the original)?

Comment: @unutbu Thanks, this is very near to what I'm looking for, what if we also want to include the count of entries in col 'A', as in mentioned in my initial question "a 4 c 2 v 1 ?? Any suggestions ??

Comment: You could compute those values using `result['A'] = df.groupby('A')['A'].count()`. I've edited the post above to show the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'v'],
                   'B': ['d', 'd', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'g', 'g'],
                   'C': ['ii', 'g', 'g', 'k', 'k', 'ii', 'p'],
                   'D': ['domain', 'domain', 'domain', 'motif', 
                         'motif', 'motif', 'domain']})

n = [name for name,g in df.groupby('A')] # remember the index names
d= [[name]*g['A'].count() + g[['B','C','D']].values.flatten().tolist() for name, g in df.groupby('A')]
rslt = pd.DataFrame([dict((x,r.count(x)) for x in r) for r in d]).fillna(0)

rslt['count'] = rslt[n].sum(axis=1)
rslt.set_index(pd.Index(n), inplace=True)
rslt.drop(n, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**step by step intuition:**

> 1. group based on column `A` and `flatten` each group to a list. I also convert the group name to a list with the number of occurrence.

```
d
Out[138]: 
[['a',
  'a',
  'a',
  'a',
  'd',
  'ii',
  'domain',
  'd',
  'g',
  'domain',
  'h',
  'g',
  'domain',
  'i',
  'k',
  'motif'],
 ['c', 'c', 'i', 'k', 'motif', 'g', 'ii', 'motif'],
 ['v', 'g', 'p', 'domain']]
```

> 2. form the prototype of final `DataFrame`. First using python build-int `count` to count the number of occurrence of each element inside each list and form the desired data-structure using `generator`. Finally fill `NaN` with `0`.

```
pd.DataFrame([dict((x,r.count(x)) for x in r) for r in d]).fillna(0)
Out[141]:
   a  c  d  domain  g  h  i  ii  k  motif  p  v
0  4  0  2       3  2  1  1   1  1      1  0  0
1  0  2  0       0  1  0  1   1  1      2  0  0
2  0  0  0       1  1  0  0   0  0      0  1  1
```

> 3. Convert the `DataFrame` prototype into the way we want

```
rslt
Out[143]: 
   d  domain  g  h  i  ii  k  motif  p  count
a  2       3  2  1  1   1  1      1  0      4
c  0       0  1  0  1   1  1      2  0      2
v  0       1  1  0  0   0  0      0  1      1
```